# Running `nano` uses the old nano(2.0.6) even though nano 3.0 is installed

Tags: macos, command-line, bash, homebrew, path

I installed nano 3.0 with `brew install nano`, but when I run `nano --version`, it shows version 2.0.6, which is what came with macOS.

Screenshot:
[image]

`echo $PATH` also shows that `/usr/local/bin` is listed before `/usr/bin`

How do I make running `nano` use version 3.0 and not 2.0.6?

[This](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/211497/install-new-nano-2-4-using-brew-but-still-uses-old-versions-symbolic-link-not) doesn't help as nano is already in `/usr/local/bin` and `/usr/local/bin` is listed first in `$PATH` and `/etc/paths`.

Comment: You don't make nano "use" anything.  You run the executable you want, from the shell.  Bash keeps a hash of where binaries are, if you type 'type nano', and it shows you the system-provided one, restart your shell or use the command 'hash -r' to force the shell to re-hash the paths.  Also, 'cat /etc/paths' is meaningless, instead 'echo $PATH'.

Comment: @MarcWilson Thanks. Could you post the `hash -r` solution as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: `/etc/paths` doesn't matter much, it's a mere template to build your `PATH` env variable, which may be later modified. So you should rather check output of `echo $PATH`

Comment: Did you try restarting your terminal session?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't make nano "use" anything. You run the executable you want, from the shell. Bash keeps a hash of where binaries are. If you type `type nano`, and it shows you the system-provided one, restart your shell or use the command `hash -r` to force the shell to re-hash the paths. Also, `cat /etc/paths` is meaningless, instead `echo $PATH`.

Answer (score 0):

Use the console command `which nano` to determine which copy of `nano` the shell is finding as it walks through your `$PATH`.

`echo $PATH` to see what `$PATH` presently contains.

If you give an *explicit file reference* to the executable file that you wish to execute, the shell will of course execute that file.  Otherwise, it will search `$PATH`, and the `which` command gives you the outcome of that search process.

Comment: Shells keep a history of previous run commands and consult that list before searching $PATH. The comment by Marc Wilson is the correct answer.

Comment: Now, I have never, ever heard that!  Can you please point me to a reference, say in `man bash`, that confirms this?  (On my system, the man-page says zippety-doo-dah zilch about the command.)

Comment: You can start with `help hash` in your `bash` shell and from the Bash Reference Manual- `Bash uses a hash table to remember the full pathnames of executable files to avoid multiple PATH searches `

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I've already tried this and it didn't work. Marc Wilson's comment worked, so I'm just waiting for him to post it as an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Please check your aliases. You may have defined your nano alias to point to the old version of nano

```
$ alias
alias firefox='open -a /Applications/Firefox.app'
alias itune='open -a /Applications/iTunes.app'
alias safari='open -a /Applications/Safari.app'
alias showhidden='ls -al | grep '\''@'\'' | grep -v '\''.DS_Store'\'''
alias showpath='set | grep "^PATH="'
alias textedit='open -e '
alias tofu='open -a /Applications/Tofu.app'
```